# Truecrypt partly encrypted

Tags: windows-7, encryption, data-recovery, formatting, truecrypt

My friend tried to encrypt his external hard drive with Truecrypt in Windows 7, but he realized that he forgot the password, so he stopped the encryption at ~30%. Is there a way for him to at least recover the other ~70% without a password? A dialog box comes up when the drive is plugged in along the lines of "You need to format this drive before you can use it."

Comment: It's easier to just format the disk and restore the backup you made before you started. But see http://superuser.com/q/11160/52492

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to retrieve some of the remaining ~70% with data recovery tools but if your friend thinks he stands a chance of remembering the password then another approach would be to  complete the encryption process. If he remembers the password then he gets 100% of his data. If he can't, he gets 0%.

According to the [TrueCrypt documentation](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-encryption)  an interrupted system encryption can be resumed. That should (hopefully) also apply to non-system drives providing that the filesystem is NTFS and you're using TrueCrypt 6.1 or later and Windows Vista or Windows 7. I'm inferring this from the [FAQ: Can I encrypt a partition/drive without losing the data currently stored on it?](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq)

Be aware that any data recovery attempt on the drive prior to completing the encryption may overwrite some of the already encrypted data and render it unmountable/corrupted even if you do manage to complete the encryption process. Best of luck.